# Sort items in cycle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm having trouble explaining what I am looking for so I will provide an example, let's say I have this array:

```
[
  [1, 2],
  [1, 3],
  [1, 4],
  [2, 3],
  [2, 4],
  [3, 4]
]
```

rather than sorting it by the first column, I would like it to cycle through the first column, so instead of `1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3` it would do: `1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1`

resulting in:

```
[
  [1, 2],
  [2, 3],
  [3, 4],
  [1, 3],
  [2, 4],
  [1, 4]
]
```

Even better would be if it could cycle through both columns to prevent two numbers in a row as much as possible, the ideal solution would sort the original array as:

```
[
  [1, 2],
  [3, 4],
  [1, 3],
  [2, 4],
  [1, 4],
  [2, 3]
]
```

Leading to the maximum spacing between repeating numbers for each inner array (both columns being taken into account).

I hope I have provided sufficient information, and I will greatly appreciate any advise, I am fairly clueless so far, searching has yeilded me nothing.

Comment: I don't understand cycling through both columns hence can't write a solution for this..

Comment: Does the distance between the adjacent items matters, or is it just that it is better for them to be different?

Comment: Cycling doesn't ensure or maximize alternation. For example, `[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4]` would result in `[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 1]` (three 1's at the end), although you can arrange the numbers without repetition: `[1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1]`

Answer (score 2):

I will only address the first part of your question as I don't understand what you mean by "Even better would be if it could cycle through both columns to prevent two numbers in a row as much as possible...". The clause "as much as possible" is especially troublesome, as it refers to an unspecified criterion.

Let `arr` be your array. The elements are sorted in your example, but if they were not, the first step would be:

```
arr.sort!
```

See [Array#sort!](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-sort-21) and [Array#<=>](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) for an explanation of how Ruby sorts arrays whose elements are arrays.

There are many ways to obtain the desired ordering. Here is one that uses [Enumerable#chunk](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-chunk):

```
arr.chunk(&:first).flat_map {|_,a| a.map.with_index {|i,b| [b,i]}}.sort.map(&:last)
  #=> [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [1, 3], [2, 4], [1, 4]]
```

The steps are as follows:

```
e = arr.chunk(&:first)
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x007fa01a8141d0>:each>
```

We can see the elements of this enumerator, which are passed to the block by [Enumerator#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Enumerator.html#method-i-each) (which calls [Array#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each)), by converting it to an array:

```
e.to_a
  #=> [[1, [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4]]], [2, [[2, 3], [2, 4]]], [3, [[3, 4]]]]
```

Continuing:

```
f = e.flat_map { |_,a| a.map.with_index { |i,b| [b,i] } }
  #=> [[0, [1, 2]], [1, [1, 3]], [2, [1, 4]], [0, [2, 3]], [1, [2, 4]], [0, [3, 4]]] 
g = f.sort
  #=> [[0, 1, 2], [0, 2, 3], [0, 3, 4], [1, 1, 3], [1, 2, 4], [2, 1, 4]] 
g.map(&:last)
  #=> [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [1, 3], [2, 4], [1, 4]]
```

Let's look more closely at the calculation of `f`:

```
h = e.flat_map
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x007fa01a8141d0>:each>:flat_map>
h.to_a
  #=> [[1, [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4]]], [2, [[2, 3], [2, 4]]], [3, [[3, 4]]]]
```

You can think of `h` as a "compound" enumerator.

The first value of `h`, `[1, [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4]]]`, is passed to the block and captured by the block variables using *parallel* (or *multiple*) *assignment*:

```
i, a = h.next
  #=> [1, [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4]]] 
i #=> 1 
a #=> [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4]]
```

As `i` is not used in the block calculation, it is customary to replace that block variable with the local variable `_`.

We can now perform the block calculation:

```
a.map.with_index { |i,b| [b,i] } 
  #=> [[0, [1, 2]], [1, [1, 3]], [2, [1, 4]]]
```

The remaining calculations are performed similarly.

Comment: Instead of building an array with new `[index, x, y]` elements, I would keep / embed the original elements via `[index, [x, y]]`, i.e. `arr.chunk(&:first).flat_map { |_, a| a.map.with_index { |b, i| [i, b] } }.sort.map(&:last)`.

Comment: Good suggestion. I've edited to incorporate it. Thanks. Readers: another way of viewing @Stefan's comment is that if, for example, `a = [[2,[1,3]], [1,[2,4]]]`, `a.sort.map(&:last)` and `a.map(&:flatten).sort.map { |b| b.last(2) }` both yield the same result: `[[2, 4], [1, 3]]`.  I effectively had the latter in my initial answer.

Answer (score 1):

you could try this

```
def func ary
  ret = []
  # group by first ones, and each sort by second ones
  a = ary.group_by{|i| i[0]}.map{|_,i| i.sort_by{|j| j[1]}}
  # add to ret
  (0...a.map{|i| i.size}.max).map{
    a.map{|i| ret << i.shift}
  }
  ret.compact
end
a = [[1, 2],[1, 3],[1, 4],[2, 3],[2, 4],[3, 4]]
p func(a)
#=> [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [1, 3], [2, 4], [1, 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the initial array is sorted by the first element:

```
arr =
  [
    [1, 2],
    [1, 3],
    [1, 4],
    [2, 3],
    [2, 4],
    [3, 4],
  ]

res = []
arr_dup = arr.dup
remaining_values = arr_dup.map { |el| el[0] }
current_value = remaining_values.first
loop do
  arr_dup.each_with_index do |el, index|
    if el[0] >= current_value
      res << el
      current_value = remaining_values.select { |v| v > el[0] }.first || remaining_values.first
      remaining_values.delete_at(remaining_values.index(current_value))
      arr_dup.delete_at(index)
      break
    end
  end
  break if remaining_values.empty?
end

p arr #=> [[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4]]
p res #=> [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [1, 3], [2, 4], [1, 4]]
```

Few tests:

```
[[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4], [5, 1], [20, 2]] =>
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [5, 1], [20, 2], [1, 3], [2, 4], [1, 4]]

[[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 3], [2, 4], [3, 4], [5, 1], [5, 2], [20, 2]] =>
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [5, 1], [20, 2], [1, 3], [2, 4], [5, 2], [1, 4]]
```